# Difference between React.HTMLProps<HTMLDivElement> and React.DetailedHTMLProps<React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement>?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I tried to create the following interfaces and types to see the difference:

```
interface Props1 extends React.DetailedHTMLProps<React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement> {}
interface Props2 extends React.HTMLProps<HTMLDivElement> {}

type Dif1 = Omit<Props1, keyof Props2>;
type Dif2 = Omit<Props2, keyof Props1>;
```

It seems like `Dif1` is `{}` but `Dif2` has a lot more properties like `allowFullScreen`, `allowTransparency`, etc. But as far as I know,  `allowFullScreen` and `allowTransparency` are attributes for `iframe` element. So how come it shows up in `Props2` where I only want to extend attributes on `div` element? What are the use cases for `Props1` and `Props2` respectively?

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is that `DetailedHTMLProps<E, T>` only extends `HTMLAttributes<T>` but `React.HTMLProps<T>` extends `AllHTMLAttributes<T>`, which then itself extends `HTMLAttributes<T>`.

Use `React.ComponentWithRef<"tag-here">` or `React.ComponentWithoutRef<"tag-here">` when you want to have the narrowest set of HTML props for your component. Use `React.HTMLProps<HTMLElement>` when you want the widest.

---

What ends up happening is when you pass `HTMLDivElement` into the generic type parameter of `HTMLProps<T>`, you're first taking a stop at `AllHTMLAttributes<T>` before going through the inheritance hierarchy down through `HTMLAttributes<T>`, and eventually ending at `DOMAttributes<T>`. This gives you the kitchen sink of all HTML attributes, which makes sense. The only thing that the generic parameter `HTMLDivElement` is doing here is being drilled down into a `ClassAttributes<T>` interface that grabs the `LegacyRef<T>` for your component and also into the eventual `DOMAttributes<T>` interface that uses `T` to correctly type all of the event handlers like `onClick`, `onDrag`, `onBlur`, and the many others. **Passing `HTMLDivElement` into `HTMLProps<T>` will do virtually nothing to narrow the type of props that are returned**.

When you use `DetailedHTMLProps<E extends HTMLAttributes<T>, T>` however, based on what `E` is passed in, you will access the narrowest relevant interface. Note that when you choose the `<a>` tag, you're accessing a uniquely different interface than when you choose the `<div>` or `<summary>` tag, which both share `React.HTMLAttributes<T>`

```
interface DetailedHTMLProps<E extends HTMLAttributes<T>, T> = E & ClassAttributes<T>;

interface JSX.IntrinsicElements {
  a: React.DetailedHTMLProps<React.AnchorHTMLAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement>, HTMLAnchorElement>;
  // ... some distance down
  div: React.DetailedHTMLProps<React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement>;
  // ... some distance down
  summary: React.DetailedHTMLProps<React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>, HTMLElement>;
  // ...
}
```

---

As of React 17.0 (when I'm writing this), the calling code should use `ComponentPropsWithRef<T extends ElementType>` or `ComponentPropsWithoutRef<T extends ElementType>` and typescript should get the detailed props for you based on the type parameter passed in.

```
export type MyType = React.ComponentPropsWithoutRef<"div">;

// if we follow the type magic to its conclusion
React.ComponentPropsWithoutRef<"div"> = PropsWithoutRef<ComponentProps<"div">>;
ComponentProps<"div"> = JSX.IntrinsicElements["div"]
JSX.IntrinsicElements["div"] = React.DetailedHTMLProps<React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement>;
```