# TypeScript & React: What's the difference between 'React.HTMLProps<T>' and 'JSX.IntrinsicElements["T"]'

Tags: html, reactjs, typescript, react-props

I am looking for the most "canonical" and/or "up-to-date" way to add **a set of default HTML attributes** as a **set of allowed TypeScript props** to a customized, "enhanced" HTML component, let's say a `Button`.

I found two type definitions. The first is `React.HTMLProps<T>`, the second `JSX.IntrinsicElements["T"]`.

So I can Enhance my `Button` either this way:

```
type Props = {
  children: React.ReactNode
  onClick?: (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => void
  type?: "button" | "submit" | "reset"
  className?: string
} & React.HTMLProps<HTMLButtonElement>
```

or like that:

```
type Props = {
  children: React.ReactNode
  onClick?: (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => void
  type?: "button" | "submit" | "reset"
  className?: string
} & JSX.IntrinsicElements["button"]
```

I've tried both ways and both of them seem to work fine (no squigly red lines).

The question is: Is there a significant difference between those type definitions? Should I use rather `React.HTMLProps<T>`, `JSX.IntrinsicElements["T"]`, or is it just a matter of personal preference?

Thank you.

[Slightly related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64867112/difference-between-react-htmlpropshtmldivelement-and-react-detailedhtmlpropsr)