# What's the difference between React.ComponentPropsWithoutRef and React.ComponentPropsWithRef in react typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

What's the difference between them and are there any documentation for this stuff? In my case I wanted to define an interface which extends the props of a component and was confused about which one to use and where to use them.

Comment: It is defined in [DefinitelyTyped/types/react/index.d.ts](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react/index.d.ts#L838). See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/69694152/7556457